# Strange graphic issue after notebook wake up

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I often suspending my system and always after wake up I've got strange graphic issues in some apps. [Here's whats happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZKhx.png). It's not only with spotify, but also with qBittorent, sometimes Chromium browser. 
Im using xubuntu 15.10, my notebook has two graphic:

- Intel HD4600
- nVidia GTX960M

I've tried to reinstall nvidia drivers, but nothig change. It is really frustrating, don't know what more can I do. Please, give me some suggestions...